# Error when assigning value for matrix element with Equation

Tags: java, ejml

I have several simple lines of code in Java using ejml Equation as follows:

```
eq.process("T = zeros(2,3)");
eq.process("T(1,1)=10");
eq.process("T(1,0)=1");
eq.process("T(1,2)=8");
```

The last line doesn't work, throwing error "Submatrix out of bounds. Lower extent".
Apparently, matrix T has size of 2x3 and indexes start from 0 so T(1,2) mus be valid.
I also tried to convert to raw matrix as follows:

```
DenseMatrix64F m=eq.lookupMatrix("T");
m.set(1, 2, 7);
```

And it works.
Is it a bug from this library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a bug.  Internally the bounds check was being done col,row instead of row,col.

Latest github code has the fix.  You can also checkout the follow SHA.

```
ec2dffbabc38c1e86f1ef58da2553cec9287b0f3
```

---

Asking questions on Stackoverflow is fine since more people see it.  However please report bugs and feature requests using github and the message board. Those will send me a message right away, but who knows when I'll see it over here.

Comment: Thanks, ok, I'll do it